# CloudBuild --cache-from for dependencies of CloudFunctions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

Several cloud functions use the same requirements: a few libraries and a utility module in localpackage. All of those functions are built and deployed by CloudBuild.

Is there any way to use CloudBuild '--cache-from' feature to use the same base for all those cloud functions?

Here are the steps in yaml file to build and deploy a cloud function:

```
steps:
  # create gcf source directory
- name: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      echo 'Creating gcf_source directory for ${_GCF_NAME}'

      mkdir _gcf_source
      cp -r cloudfuncs/${_GCF_NAME}/. _gcf_source
      rm -f _gcf_source/readme.md
      mkdir _gcf_source/localpackage
      touch _gcf_source/localpackage/__init__.py
      cp cloudfuncs/localpackage/gcf_utils.py _gcf_source/localpackage

      echo "" >> _gcf_source/requirements.txt
      cat cloudfuncs/localpackage/requirements.txt >> _gcf_source/requirements.txt

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions
  - deploy
  - ${_GCF_NAME}
```

Comment: The question seems incomplete. Please, review the content.

Comment: Can you elaborate please. I might be to involved to understand what's missing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Build is serverless and you can't keep the data from one execution to another one.

However, you have 2 solutions

- Build a container with your localpackage and use it in your subsequent deployment as the container of the step.
- Store the file in Google Cloud Storage and load them in your Cloud Build workspace as first step of your deployments. The [artifact](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#artifacts) feature could help you in this task (to save files).

Comment: Yep, I thought so, but I've got no idea how to do that. Is there any yaml file example you could share or any article where they show how to build a container first and then use that as a base? Thanks!